Why does the hanging garden hose with water flowing out never stop swinging, while the pendulum eventually stops?
Why does the hanging garden hose with water flowing out never stop swinging, while the pendulum eventually stops?
In my understanding, artificially bending a garden hose (without a nozzle at the outlet) will generate a force F perpendicular to the hose, which will push the hose to swing. However, due to air resistance, F will gradually decrease, so the swing amplitude of the hose should gradually decrease, and eventually the hose will stop swinging. Why does it look like the hose never stops swinging?

Not really comparable since the water source is continually putting energy back into the system

@Triatticus  F is caused by artificially bending the hose, and this force is weakened by the frictional force of air, so the hose should eventually stop swinging, although water still flows out of the hose. Otherwise, why does the pendulum eventually stop swinging even though gravity persists?

Gravity doesn't continually add energy to the system, a comparable system would be a person being pushed on a swing.

@Triatticus But F is caused by artificial bending.

In the flowing situation, you are constantly supplying energy to the hose via that flowing water.

@Triatticus The force F caused by the bending of the hose is provided by the flowing water, but when the hose is no longer bent, the water will not provide F.

The water is always providing that force mostly at higher flow rates when it becomes turbulent and the flow isn't always parallel to the hose walls regardless of the hose orientation.

@Triatticus If we don't discuss unstable flow first, how can we forcefully bend the hose?
Assuming that the diameter of the hose along its length remains constant and there is no acceleration when water flows in the hose, how can there be a reaction force at the outlet section of the hose?

This is discussing too much in the comments suffice to say you could do this experiment yourself by adjusting the flow rate of the hose to find when the turbulent flow isn't enough to restore energy to the motion, resulting in the damping removing more energy than is being supplied.

@Triatticus  Turbulence is relatively complex, so laminar flow should be discussed first rather than turbulence.

This is called the garden hose instability. The behavior depends on several factors, including the force of gravity, the stiffness of the pipe and the flow rate.
For low flow rates you can get a steady or a damped oscillation, but for higher flow rates the system becomes unstable and “flutters”. The lateral force F does not damp at those flow rates (and at lower flow rates the damping is usually due to the stiffness of the hose rather than air resistance) because the force at the outlet is high enough to cause the pipe to buckle.
In principle, if you lined the hose up perfectly straight, the flow would be straight, but at high enough flow rates it is unstable and any slight perturbation will cause the hose to buckle and the fluttering motion to begin as the nozzle turns and causes the hose to accelerate laterally.
Here is a nice video explaining in more depth:
https://www.coursera.org/lecture/fluid-solid-interaction/6-1-the-garden-hose-instability-fvRjz
And here is a slow motion video of the flutter
https://youtu.be/KMxyy5NrZ-o
As you can see, it does not stay straight.

But the inertia of an object causes it to move in a straight line. Even if there is slight instability at high flow rates, the hose should eventually tend towards a straight line. Why not?

@enbin The system is unstable at high flow rates. Unstable means that it tends away from equilibrium. So it does not tend towards a straight line, it tends away from a straight line. That is what it means for this system to be unstable. You are describing an unstable system as though it should be stable

https://youtu.be/KMxyy5NrZ-o   The speed of this flow is not high, but it also becomes a straight line.

Instability always has some reasons, what causes instability?

In this case the instability happens when the force from the outlet is high enough to cause buckling in the pipe. Once the pipe buckles then the force from the outlet no longer damps the oscillation.
